# Reversing a string with weird results

Tags: c++

I'm a novice programmer just trying out some exercise on C++. In this case the exercise was to reverse a string. However, when I tried to reverse a string, on some occasions the output had some weird characters at the back. Could anyone tell me what's wrong? I've tried looking through the code thoroughly and can't figure out what's wrong.

Example:

Input : Hello

Output: olleH0] 
        �k�]�y��jv�@�y�

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

string FirstReverse(string str) { 
    int k,y,z;
    k = strlen(str.c_str()); 
    y = k-1;

    char str2[k];

    for (z = 0; z < k; z++) {
        str2[z] = str.c_str()[y];

        if (y==0) break; 
        else y--;
        }

  return str2; 

}

int main() { 
    string x;  
    getline(cin, x);    
    cout << FirstReverse(x);
    return 0;

}
```

EDIT:

Turns out I could do it without using C styled strings by simply:

```
int k,y,z;
    k = str.length(); 
    y = k-1;

    string str2;

    for (z = 0; z < k; z++) {
        str2 += str[y];
        y--;
        }
  return str2;
```

Comment: For `str2`, you need to allocate another character for the null terminator and set it to `\0`.

Comment: `char str2[k];` is not valid C++. (It's a GCC extension.) In any event, why are you doing this in C-style strings? `std::string` overloads `operator []`.

Comment: Also note you missed a `#include <string>`.

Comment: @T.C. I'm not sure what you mean. I tried using string str2 but it gave me an error because I can't use str2[k]

Comment: @user3763267, I [call BS](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75b6fa622faf24bf) on that if you're indexing a `std::string` with an integral type.

Comment: `strlen(str.c_str());` Uhhhh.. no. `str.length()`

Comment: I have edited it to do away with the C style strings (at the bottom of the original qn). Thanks everyone for your help, I learnt more than I originally asked. @dyp thanks for that tip.

Comment: @user3763267, your code looks good to me. On what platform are you testing this?

Comment: @RSahu Thanks! I'm using Geany on Linux. EDIT: Btw someone edited my code to make it look nicer so it's not my original.

Comment: Oh I just realise that the edit was rejected but I inadvertently accepted it. No idea how, sorry. Reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`algorithm` includes a function called `reverse`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string my_string = "Hello World";
   reverse(my_string.begin(), my_string.end());
   cout << my_string << endl; 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: but... but... then you don’t get to use `strlen(str.c_str());`